# Why $pV=\frac13Nm\langle c^2\rangle$ can be applied to diatomic molecules?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

For a monoatomic molecule,
$$
\frac{1}{2} m \langle c^2\rangle = \frac{3}{2}kT.
$$
If I multiply by total number of molecules,
$$
\frac{1}{2} Nm \langle c^2\rangle = \frac{3}{2} NkT = \frac{3}{2} pV.
$$
Dividing both sides by $3/2$,
$$
\frac{1}{3} Nm \langle c^2\rangle = pV\,.
$$
However, for diatomic molecules,

$m \langle c^2\rangle/2$ is **not** $3kT/2$. The energy of the molecules is instead given by equipartition theorem.

So I was expecting a different equation for diatomic molecules, where the coefficient $1/3$ is $1/f$, $f$ being the degree of freedom. However, my notes say that $Nm \langle c^2\rangle/3 = pV$ can apply for diatomic molecules so now I'm confused. What's wrong with my reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"$\tfrac 12 m\overline{c^2}$ is **not** $\tfrac 32 kT$"

Yes it is. There is mean energy $\tfrac 12 kT$ per degree of freedom, and a molecule, monatomic or diatomic, has 3 degrees of translational freedom.

"The energy of the molecules is instead given by equipartition theorem."

Yes, but without the "instead". The equipartition theorem tells us that, for a diatomic molecule, rotation gives us 2 more degrees of freedom, each with a mean energy of $\frac 12 kT$.[Quantum considerations tell us that rotation about the line joining the atoms' centres won't usually happen.]

So your equation, $pV =\frac 13 Nm\overline{c^2}$ holds as well for a diatomic gas as a monatomic, under ideal gas conditions (few molecules per unit volume).

What IS different for ideal monatomic and diatomic gases is their internal energies: $\frac 32 NkT$ and $\frac 52 NkT$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So to confirm, E = 3/2 kT and total KE = 3/2 NkT can be applied to diatomic molecules, but U = 3/2 NkT is only for monoatomic molecules?

Comment: " total KE = 3/2 NkT can be applied to diatomic molecules". Not total KE but, for a diatomic molecule, total TRANSLATIONAL KE, that is total KE of motion in the $x$, $y$ and $z$ directions of its centre of gravity. The other $2\times \frac 12 NkT$ of internal energy of a diatomic gas is also kinetic: (rotation about two axes at right angles to the line joining the centre of the atoms). The total translational kinetic energy is the same as for a monatomic gas at the same temperature: $\frac 32 NkT$.

Comment: Ohhh, thanks, so to confirm again, E = 3/2 kT can be applied to diatomic molecules, but that only considers the translational ke?

Comment: Yes, that's it! Good!  Correction to previous comment: for *centre of gravity* read *centre of mass*.

Comment: Um.. sorry for asking such an elementary question but I just want to clarify my doubt here.. so if we take two gases at same temperature , and one being diatomic and one being monoatomic, then for both of them their PV = 2/3(Translational KE)?

Comment: Yes, that's right. For both, $pV=NkT=\tfrac 23 N\tfrac 32 kT$.